# How to give preference to a particular dictionary in sightly?

Tags: dictionary, internationalization, aem, sightly

I have multiple dictionaries under `"/etc/project_name/i18n"` (e.g `"/etc/project_name/i18n/default"` and `"/etc/project_name/i18n/overlay"`).

My requirement is picking up the values first from overlay path and if the overlay dictionary is empty, select the default path.

With the usage of internationalization in sightly, I am always getting the key values from "default" dictionary first. Is there a way to change this order of preference?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both '**default**' and '**overlay**' are **jcr:language**, you can provide explicit preference as such:

```
${'key' @ i18n, locale='overlay'}
```

For recurring implementation:

```
<sly data-sly-call="${i18nOverlay @ key='key'}"></sly>

<template data-sly-template.i18nOverlay="${@ key}">
    ${key @ i18n, locale='overlay'}
</template>
```

Ref: [HTL Expression Language](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/expression-language.html)